# How to provide odometry from Gmapping?

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to try the Gmapping package. But have doubt and question regarding the odometry. So how Gmapping provide an odometry? I have IMU and laser as sensor sources. So what do I need in order that Gmapping publish the odometry ?? Any documentation or example for helps?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51846/how-to-provide-odometry-from-gmapping?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

gmapping doesn't provide odometry information, instead, u have to publish odometry information towards gmapping package, which is performed in tf transformation.

---

Originally posted by [Kent](https://answers.ros.org/users/3533/kent/) with karma: 140 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-01-09**:
ok. Thanks. Any documentation or helps regarding that tf transformation??

**Comment by [Kent](https://answers.ros.org/users/3533/kent/) on 2013-01-09**:
u can check http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf and http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-01-09**:
ok. Thanks. And regarding Gmapping??Any documentation or examples?

**Comment by [Kent](https://answers.ros.org/users/3533/kent/) on 2013-01-09**:
[www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping)

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-01-10**:
So I have to subscribe to TF massage in order to get the position , yes??

**Comment by [Kent](https://answers.ros.org/users/3533/kent/) on 2013-01-10**:
in fact, u have to publish TF message so that the Gmapping stack can work properly.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-01-10**:
and subscribe to laser scan message or??